# Error: The name 'm' does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am using the following:

```
@model IEnumerable<Abc.Service.Shared.Models.Company>

@Html.TextBoxFor(m >= m.Name , new { @id="CompanySearch" })
```

I get the error:

> CS0103: The name 'm' does not exist in the current context

Can anyone help me solve this?

---

After correcting the arrow, I get another error:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name , new { @id="CompanySearch" })
```

> CS0411: The type arguments for method 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBoxFor<TModel,TProperty>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,TProperty>>, string)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So 2 issues with your code,

1. as most of the others have pointed out, your syntax error ">="
2. Your model is a type of `IEnumerable<Abc.Service.Shared.Models.Company>`. When you do @Html.TextBoxFor, you are trying to get a property from the model. In your case, you are trying to get property "Name" from the model IEnumerable, which obviously won't work.

I assume that Name is a property of your `Abc.Service.Shared.Models.Company` object and you are trying to display a list of textbox. Here is a reference how you do this: 
[MVC with TextBoxFor having same id within loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16955178/mvc-with-textboxfor-having-same-id-within-loop)

Answer (score 1):

you have syntax issue here,

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m >= m.Name , new { @id="CompanySearch" })
```

should be

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.Name , new { id = "CompanySearch" })
```

OR

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, htmlAttributes: new { id = "CompanySearch" })
```

and `Name` should be declared as `Public` in your Model,this should work for single object only,as you are using Model type as `IEnumerable`,you should use loop to access object in your `Collection`

Comment: Got a new error. CS0411: The type arguments for method 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBoxFor<TModel,TProperty>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,TProperty>>, string)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

you have syntax issue here,

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m >= m.Name , new { @id="CompanySearch" })
```

It should be like this

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name , new { @id="CompanySearch" })
```

but you cannot get/use **Name** property if u use `IEnumerable<classname>` of ur class in view
so thats why it give u error

Answer (score 0):

Please see the syntax you have used

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m >= m.Name , new { @id="CompanySearch" })
```

**It should be like this**

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name , new { @id="CompanySearch" })
```

See this link for more about **MVC**

http://www.asp.net/mvc